# time series minute data - how to select data for given interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have timeseries data like this:

```
  ticker        close
created_at                                   
2020-06-10 17:02:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.354980
2020-06-10 18:30:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.419312
2020-06-10 18:31:00+00:00   TSLA  1018.344971
2020-06-10 18:32:00+00:00   TSLA  1018.340027
2020-06-10 18:33:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.919983
2020-06-10 18:34:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.210022
2020-06-10 18:35:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.772583
2020-06-10 18:36:00+00:00   TSLA  1016.775024
2020-06-10 18:37:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.679993
2020-06-10 18:38:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.080017
2020-06-10 18:39:00+00:00   TSLA  1013.000000
2020-06-10 18:40:00+00:00   TSLA  1008.880005
2020-06-10 18:41:00+00:00   TSLA  1011.369995
2020-06-10 18:42:00+00:00   TSLA  1012.400024
2020-06-10 18:43:00+00:00   TSLA  1013.000000
2020-06-10 18:44:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.459412
2020-06-10 18:45:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.070007
2020-06-10 18:46:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.575012
2020-06-10 18:47:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.419983
......................
```

I want to pick the close price at every 5 minute interval for example at 18:30,18:35,18:40 etc. It was suggested to use resample, however I don't wish to resample the data per se. All I want to do is get the close price at every 5 minute interval, whats the best way of going about doing that

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to resample the data?

Comment: What is our expected output from this data?  Resample will pick the times out on the 5 minute intervals.  I think this is exactly what you need if you have data every minute.

Comment: Well I need to pick an aggregation method for resampling right,  i cannot use none e.g. d=df.resample("5T").none() AFAIK.. All I want to do is just return the data at 5 min intervals

Answer (score 1):

The following `df`,

```
| date                | tick   |   price |
|:--------------------|:-------|--------:|
| 2020-06-10 18:30:00 | TSLA   | 1017.42 |
| 2020-06-10 18:31:00 | TSLA   | 1018.34 |
| 2020-06-10 18:32:00 | TSLA   | 1018.34 |
| 2020-06-10 18:33:00 | TSLA   | 1017.92 |
| 2020-06-10 18:34:00 | TSLA   | 1015.21 |
| 2020-06-10 18:35:00 | TSLA   | 1015.77 |
| 2020-06-10 18:36:00 | TSLA   | 1016.78 |
| 2020-06-10 18:37:00 | TSLA   | 1015.68 |
| 2020-06-10 18:38:00 | TSLA   | 1014.08 |
| 2020-06-10 18:39:00 | TSLA   | 1013    |
| 2020-06-10 18:40:00 | TSLA   | 1008.88 |
| 2020-06-10 18:41:00 | TSLA   | 1011.37 |
| 2020-06-10 18:42:00 | TSLA   | 1012.4  |
| 2020-06-10 18:43:00 | TSLA   | 1013    |
| 2020-06-10 18:44:00 | TSLA   | 1014.46 |
| 2020-06-10 18:45:00 | TSLA   | 1014.07 |
| 2020-06-10 18:46:00 | TSLA   | 1015.58 |
| 2020-06-10 18:47:00 | TSLA   | 1014.42 |
```

can be shown every 5min with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc):

```
df.iloc[::5]
```

which results in:

```
| date                | tick   |   price |
|:--------------------|:-------|--------:|
| 2020-06-10 18:30:00 | TSLA   | 1017.42 |
| 2020-06-10 18:35:00 | TSLA   | 1015.77 |
| 2020-06-10 18:40:00 | TSLA   | 1008.88 |
| 2020-06-10 18:45:00 | TSLA   | 1014.07 |
```

if the data has a new entry every minute, otherwise you can adapt the `stride` value of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the data at 5 min intervals, you can just get the minutes that are multiples of 5:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df = df[df['created_at'].dt.strftime('%M').astype(int) % 5 ==0]
print(df)

                  created_at ticker        close
1  2020-06-10 18:30:00+00:00   TSLA  1017.419312
6  2020-06-10 18:35:00+00:00   TSLA  1015.772583
11 2020-06-10 18:40:00+00:00   TSLA  1008.880005
16 2020-06-10 18:45:00+00:00   TSLA  1014.070007
```